# Why does this string initialization in an if statement prevent me from printing?

Tags: c#, syntax, language-design, if-statement

i have little  problem with if

```
{
    string nom;
    string ou;
    nom = "1";
    if (nom == "1")
    {
        nom +=1;
        ou = nom;
    }
    Console.Write(ou);
}
```

but i cant print ou value  i dont know why

Comment: Not an articulate question in my opinion. Code is weird with no explanation -- why do "x += 1" on a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to set ou in an else:

```
if (nom == "1")
{
    nom +=1;
    ou = nom;
} else 
{
    ou = "blank value";
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this

```
{
    string nom;
    string ou = String.Empty;
    nom = "1";
    if (nom == "1")
    {
        nom +=1;
        ou = nom;
    }
    Console.Write(ou);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

C# compiler requires the variables to be definitely initialized before use.

Definite initialization is a compile-time thing, it doesn't consider runtime values of variables.

However, if the variable `nom` was explicitly definied as `const`, the compiler would be sure that it would not change at runtime and the `if` statement block would run and the variable `ou` would be definitely assigned to.

Answer (score 6):

Does this even compile?

`nom` is a `string` - how can you do `nom += 1`?

Comment: The same way string foo = "User id=" + 10; works. The result is "User id=10". Here, nom would be "11". That might not be the expected result, admittedly...

Comment: 1 will be converted to string before concatenation. it's equal to nom += 1.ToString()

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing the second line with

```
string ou = null;
```

The problem is that if nom turns out not to equal "1", the variable ou won't have been initialized. The compiler here wants to guarantee that ou has been assigned a value.

Answer (score 3):

This is because ou is unassigned outside the scope of the if block.  Change the declaration line to `string ou = string.Empty;` and it shoudl work.

Answer (score 3):

This snippet won't even compile, let alone printing `ou`. C# enforces all variables to be initialized before accessing, which is not always true in your case. Thus changing

```
string ou;
```

to, say:

```
string ou = "";
```

will do just fine.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: what exactly don't you agree with?

Comment: I did not downvote it, but my issue with it is the ="", it should be = String.Empty for readability reasons mostly.